# ZeroMq Golang binding cannot build on Windows

Tags: go, zeromq

I'm trying to get Go ZMQ4 binding to work on windows.
Unfortunately, i'm not able to build the zmq library neither Gozmq software and get the following errors:

```
*** Since this library must not contain undefined symbols,
```

*** because either the platform does not support them or**
 it was explicitly requested with -no-undefined,
 **libtool will only create a static version of it.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/e/Users/mmarques/Desktop/zeromq-4.0.5/src'
make[1]: Leaving directory`/e/Users/mmarques/Desktop/zeromq-4.0.5/src'
Making all in doc
make[1]: Entering directory `/e/Users/mmarques/Desktop/zeromq-4.0.5/doc'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for`all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/e/Users/mmarques/Desktop/zeromq-4.0.5/doc'
Making all in perf
make[1]: Entering directory`/e/Users/mmarques/Desktop/zeromq-4.0.5/perf'
  CXX    local_lat.o
  CXXLD  local_lat.exe
local_lat.o: In function `main':
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:45: undefined referenc
e to`__imp_zmq_init'
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:51: undefined referenc
e to `__imp_zmq_socket'
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:57: undefined referenc
e to`__imp_zmq_bind'
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:63: undefined referenc
e to `__imp_zmq_msg_init'
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:69: undefined referenc
e to`__imp_zmq_recvmsg'
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:75: undefined referenc
e to `__imp_zmq_msg_size'
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:79: undefined referenc
e to`__imp_zmq_sendmsg'
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:72: undefined referenc
e to `__imp_zmq_strerror'
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:86: undefined referenc
e to`__imp_zmq_msg_close'
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:92: undefined referenc
e to `__imp_zmq_sleep'
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:94: undefined referenc
e to`__imp_zmq_close'
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:100: undefined referen
ce to `__imp_zmq_term'
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:102: undefined referen
ce to`__imp_zmq_strerror'
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:81: undefined referenc
e to `__imp_zmq_strerror'
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:59: undefined referenc
e to`__imp_zmq_strerror'
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:65: undefined referenc
e to `__imp_zmq_strerror'
e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:96: undefined referenc
e to`__imp_zmq_strerror'
local_lat.o:e:\Users\mmarques\Desktop\zeromq-4.0.5\perf/local_lat.cpp:88: more u
ndefined references to `__imp_zmq_strerror' follow
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [local_lat.exe] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/e/Users/mmarques/Desktop/zeromq-4.0.5/perf'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

What I've done was download Zmq Sources and perform a

> sh configure
>
> make

Can anyone help me figure out how to solve this, and setup up a Zmq Go Binding on Windows environment?

Comment: Image screen shots are **not** a good way to present text information. In the future please learn how to cut-n-paste *text* that is then easier to read, searchable, and easily cut-n-pasted further.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I edited the post to be more readable

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you have the MinGW gcc toolchain installed. Go needs it to be able to call C code from Go code which zmq4 is doing. If you check out the zmq4 repo you can see the .h header file. See: https://golang.org/doc/install and https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/.

Comment: EDIT: Also I found this issue on the zmq4 github repo: https://github.com/pebbe/zmq4/issues/3. There is an explanation on how to get zmq and zmq4 working together.